# How to call Redux-toolkit-query Manually on button click

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux-toolkit-query (RTK Query) to fetch data from the server. Now, I want to call my query on button click, not automatically. I tried this but it's not working.

```js
const { data, refetch } = useGetBusinessAreasQuery({
    enable: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    manual: true,
    refetchOnReconnect: false,
  });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to use the lazy query hook:

```js
const [ trigger, { data } ] = api.endpoints.getBuisnessAreas.useLazyQuery()

const onClick = () => {
  trigger()
}
```

Comment: `api` is the return value of `createApi` execution: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi

Answer (score 13):

This is how I did it, it's only cleaner:

in `feature/service.ts`:

```js
export const authenticationApi = createApi({

    reducerPath: 'myApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: baseUrl }),
    endpoints: builder => ({
        attemptLogin: builder.query({
            query: (credentials) => ({
                url: '/',
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            })
        })
    })
})

// The object created by createApi also returns a "lazy" version
// of each query:
export const { useLazyAttemptLoginQuery } = authenticationApi
```

And using (programmatically) it:

```js
const [getAuthenticated, { data, isLoading, error }] = useLazyAttemptLoginQuery();
```

Here you will have the `getAuthenticated` function to invoke when you need it.

References:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#hook-types

Comment: in which way this code answers the question? this is just standard use of rtk query, without being triggered manually from onClick as requested.